# PLC ST Language - Motor reverse on sensor signal

Tags: algorithm, automation, plc

I am not 100% sure if this fits StackOverflow or I should have posted on a more automation-specific StackExchange site, so my apologies to the moderators anyway.

I am trying to program an ABB PM564 PLC with CodeSys, which controls a motor connected to its ouputs (`FORWARD` is output0, `REVERSE` is output1). The scenario inputs are a `POWER` button (input0) which turns on/off the motor and a `SENSOR` (input1) which would cause the motor to invert its rotation when activated.

Cause the instant reverse would cause a jam to the motor I have to use a `delay` function (Timer On-Delay, aka TON) to pause the motor for an internal of 1sec, before changing the rotation.

Here is the block of code in Structured Text language:

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK SWITCH
VAR_INPUT
    POWER : BOOL;
    SENSOR : BOOL;
END_VAR
VAR_OUTPUT
    FORWARD : BOOL;
    REVERSE : BOOL;
END_VAR
VAR
    switch: BOOL;
    delay : TON;
END_VAR
```

-

```
delay(IN:=switch, PT:=T#1000ms);

IF POWER THEN
    IF NOT(FORWARD OR REVERSE) THEN
        FORWARD:=TRUE;
        REVERSE:=FALSE;
    END_IF;
ELSE
    FORWARD:=FALSE;
    REVERSE:=FALSE;
END_IF;

IF SENSOR THEN
    switch:=TRUE;
END_IF;

IF switch THEN
    IF FORWARD THEN
        FORWARD:=FALSE;
        IF delay.Q THEN
            REVERSE:=TRUE;
            switch:=FALSE;
        END_IF;
    END_IF;
    IF REVERSE THEN
        REVERSE:=FALSE;
        IF delay.Q THEN
            FORWARD:=TRUE;
            switch:=FALSE;
        END_IF;
    END_IF;
END_IF;
```

The problem is that `IF` block statement at line 25 of the implementation code does not seem to execute, causing the motor to pause for a sec and continue to rotate `FORWARD` every time..

Comment: Isn't there any timer reset? Also have you tried to reverse the fwd and rev commands and see if the logic reverses?

Comment: For how much time is the sensor on?

Comment: It seems it only executes the first `IF` block inside `IF switch THEN`. If I put the `IF REVERSE THEN` first it switch to `REVERSE` but it continues after every pause to rotating on `REVERSE`... The `SENSOR` should be turned off instantly as it is a button, so I pass its value to `switch` var to avoid the timer function to reset instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's my guess but the problem maybe here:

```
IF POWER THEN
    IF NOT(FORWARD OR REVERSE) THEN
        FORWARD:=TRUE;
        REVERSE:=FALSE;
    END_IF;
```

This code shall be executed on every scan of the PLC. So when the timer is running, then neither of `FORWARD` or `REVERSE` is `TRUE`. Hence this if statement executes and makes `FORWARD = TRUE`.

Try this:

```
delay(IN:=switch, PT:=T#1000ms);

IF POWER THEN
    IF (NOT(FORWARD OR REVERSE) AND NOT(switch)) THEN
        FORWARD:=TRUE;
        REVERSE:=FALSE;
        REV_DELAY:=FALSE;
        FWD_DELAY:=FALSE;
    END_IF;
ELSE
    FORWARD:=FALSE;
    REVERSE:=FALSE;
END_IF;

IF SENSOR THEN
    switch:=TRUE;
END_IF;

IF switch THEN
    IF FORWARD THEN
        FORWARD:=FALSE;
        REV_DELAY:=TRUE;
        FWD_DELAY:=FALSE;
    END_IF;
    IF REVERSE THEN
        REVERSE:=FALSE;
        FWD_DELAY:=TRUE;
        REV_DELAY:=FALSE;
    END_IF;
END_IF;

IF (switch AND delay.Q) THEN
  REVERSE:=REV_DELAY;
  FORWARD:=FWD_DELAY;
  REV_DELAY:=FALSE;
  FWD_DELAY:=FALSE;
  switch:=FALSE;
END_IF;
```

Comment: hmmm maybe you have point, but in that case I think it wouldn't pause at all. It would change instantly after I put `FORWARD:=FALSE;`

Comment: @LePhleg It will keep toggling itself till the timer is running because the timer loop will continue making it false again. In any case, try to correct it and see.

Comment: so whats your suggestion to change it to?

Comment: Simply add a check here IF NOT((FORWARD OR REVERSE) AND !switch). If switch is false, only then the statement shall execute.

Comment: That was my first guess `IF (NOT(FORWARD OR REVERSE)) AND NOT(switch) THEN` but it now seems to hang after the `SENSOR` is triggered.. like both `FORWARD` and `REVERSE` are set to false. Even enabling the `SENSOR` again doesnt change this state..

Comment: I implement your changes. Now when the `SENSOR` is on, the rotation keeps toogling instantly between `FORWARD` and `REVERSE`. There is no delay. When `SENSOR` is turned off the state remains stable.

Comment: @LePhleg Sorry a typo. (NOT(FORWARD OR REVERSE) AND NOT(switch)) I have edited it.

Comment: Dont worry, I understood what you meant. I implemented it like your edit. Unfortunately the result is still the same..

Comment: Seems like your delay function is not working as I expect it to. How long are you making the sensor ON? I'm not conversant with this language.

Comment: OMG! I had a typo when edited to the last version!! Its working @Abhishek Bansal!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH! lol :D

Comment: I've been workin on this for hours and my head was nearly to explode! Thank you so much again, my friend!

Answer (score 0):

Watch **delay.Q**, because it seams never to be true.